# Bounded linear operator, why do we only consider points in the unit circle

Tags: functional-analysis

$ \Lambda: X \times Y, X,Y$ normed is said to be a bounded linear operator if

$ \|\Lambda\| \equiv \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|\Lambda x\| < \infty$

I am trying to look for some intuition here, but I'm not sure why it suffices to consider only $\|x\| \leq 1$ to conclude boundedness. Is this due to the linear structure of the space? Or are we invoking some kind of isomorphism?

Any clarification on this would be rather helpful!

Comment: This definition is equivalent to saying $\Lambda$ is bounded if it maps bounded sets to bounded sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A linear transformation $L : X \to Y$ on normed vector spaces $X$ and $Y$ is said to be bounded if there exists some constant $M > 0$ such that 
$$
\|Lx\| \leq M\|x\|
$$
for all $x\in X$. Thus,
$$
\left\|L\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right\| = \frac{\|Lx\|}{\|x\|} \leq M
$$
for all nonzero $x\in X$. Hence,
$$
\sup_{\|x\| = 1}\|Lx\| \leq M
$$
If there exists a nonzero $x\in X$ such that $\|Lx\| = M\|x\|$, then we may define the operator norm of $L$ as
$$
\|L\| := \sup_{\|x\| = 1}\|Lx\| = M < \infty
$$

Comment: Thank you. That's terribly clear.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: How does it follow that if $\|Lx\| = M \|x\|$ for $x\in X$, then it attains the supremum at the unit-ball? In other words, why then
$$\sup\limits_{\|x\| = 1}\|Lx\| = M? $$
Why could it not attain its supremum only outside this set?

Comment: If $\|Lx\| = M\|x\|$ for some nonzero $x\in X$, then $\|L(x/\|x\|)\| = M$. Since $\|(x/\|x\|)\| = 1$, there exists a value in the unit ball $B = \{x\in X\,|\,\|x\| = 1\}$ at which $\|Lx\|$ achieves its supremum.

Comment: @K.Miller Thank you, +1.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a normed linear space satisfying the first axiom of countability then it is important that a linear functional $f$ is continuous on $X$ if and only if it is bounded. Therefore a linear functional $f$ on a normed linear space is bounded if and only if it bounded on every closed sphere $\| x \| \leq C$, but then since $f$ is linear this is equivalent to $f$ being continuous if and only if it is bounded on $\| x \| \leq 1$, this *suggests* that a sensible definition would be to take
$$
\| f \| = \sup_{\| x \| \leq 1 } |f(x)|,
$$
because therefore $f$ is continuous if and only if $\| f \|$ as defined is finite. You can further show that 
$$
\| f \| = \sup_{x \neq 0 } \frac{ | f(x) |}{\|x \|}.
$$